# CSS vertical centering split background image not overlapping

Tags: css, image, split, center

is it possible to split 2 images vertically and when resizing the browser, it wont overlap but stay vertically centered?

can the left image stay fixed so the right side of it won't cut off(overlap)

this is what i have now, but when resizing the browser smaller, it pushes the left image underneath the right. rather have the images cut off on the outer sides and never overlap each other in the middle, make sense?

```
#wrapper {
 width:1680px;
 max-width:1680px;
 height:500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#left-image {
 width: 50%;
 position:absolute;
 left: auto;
 height:500px;
}
#right-image {
 width: 50%;
 position:absolute;
 right: 0px;
 height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this jQuery plugin?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/elementcenter

It will keep elements of choice centered.

Comment: I think your suggestion is a bit heavy-handed. This should *easily* be accomplished solely within CSS, given the correct CSS. (not saying my answer is correct)

Comment: as i am already using jquery this is great! really appreciate this! sorry i'm new here and can't vote.

Answer (score 0):

for the `right-image` what happens if you use `left: 50%;` instead of `right: 0px;`?

Comment: this does not seem to change anything